# disabling entire angular component

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular application. Application consists of a parent component which then contains multiple child components. Each child component takes care of a a part of the screen, like top bar, side bar, bottom bar etc etc.

I have a requirement in which I have to grey out some of the child components based on certain state in parent component, so that user is not able to perform any action on those components views.

How can this be achieved? I understand that ng-disabled is used for disabling view elements but it can't be used for div. So what better options are available?

Comment: [disabled]="condition"

Comment: I dont think that works for divs. Would give a try though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a conditional class to parent div something like

```
<div [ngClass]="{'disabled':yourCondition}">
<your-component></your-component>
</div>
```

then in css

```
.disabled
{
  pointer-events: none;
  /* for "disabled" effect */
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-component-ratmtc)

Comment: We can still access the field by tabbing with the keyboard, and modify the value (see [the stackblitz](https://angular-parent-child-component-ratmtc.stackblitz.io/)).

Answer (score 9):

You can include the child component in a [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) container, and set the `disabled` property of that container with property binding:

```
<fieldset [disabled]="!childEnabled">
  <my-component></my-component>
</fieldset>
```

The `disabled` flag will apply to all the inputs and buttons included in the container. It will also prevent the user from accessing the fields by tabbing with the keyboard.

You can prevent the default styling associated with the `fieldset` element with the following CSS:

```
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpjdoz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.